# 64-bit integer faster approach to compare with zero

Tags: c, compare, compiler-optimization

Whereas that [zero is a special constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0#Elementary_algebra), looking for the faster approach to check *x==0*... There are some way to optimize and **to ensure that compiler will do some optimization?**

---

Illustration **only to conextualize** the comparison with zero, because Stackoverflow demands a piece of code to be a valid question.

```
#include <stdint.h>

_Bool is_zero(int64_t checkMe)
{   /* ensure that compiler will do some optimization */
   return checkMe==0x00000000LL;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you can't do much wrong when checking for zero: https://godbolt.org/z/Ys_RCz

Comment: Hi @tkausl, good benchmark (!). Well, even with no optimization, is a good answer (!!), to "proof" that is an optimization need only to add `int64_t is_nonzero(int64_t checkMe) {return checkMe==3;}` showing cont-example.

Comment: First of all - if you need to care about such a micro optimizations - your algorithm is bad. Secondly check it yourself: https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Comment: @thanks @P__J__, for good answer and more this link where the instruction table say that `TEST r,r` and `CMP r,r/i` have the same latency, so are equivalent — thanks to show that there are no real performance gain when compiler replace `cmp` to `test` for that Intel or AMD processors... It is a valid line of reasoling answer. The question is generic  (thanks your suggestion of function will be inlined),  about "any  processor", needs only a demonstration... Maybe I have failed to offer better contextualization, here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2892097/70274

Comment: C code has litte to do with the generated machine code, except for the behaviour. Did you check the machine code with optimisations enabled? What is wrong about that generated code? Where do you see potential for optimisations? Why do you think the compiler will not recognize the patter and generate the best code already? Which target architecture? Which toolchain? Why use a function at all? Do you enable LTO?

Comment: Hi @toohonestforthissite, sorry, perhaps I not understand you, and perhaps I am mixing discussions about "generic compiler pragmas/directives" with discussion of the performance of very specific assembler (`test` vs `cmp`), but notice that its **only to "proof" that the compiler is trying to optimize**... Please check the context link above and post a new answer: if @Mickey695 is wrong I will review.

Comment: Comments are for clarification, not to answer. I used the according to site rules. You are expected to provide **all** necessary information **in your question**. Same for answers, btw. Expecting clarification. With >4k rep you should know [ask] and how this site works. Maybe you re-take the [tour], too.

Comment: thanks @toohonestforthissite. So, I understand that you agree with the Mikey's answer  and not was you that down-voted it, at same instant of your comment.

Comment: @PeterKrauss there is nothing like a generic question when we discuss optimizations which are 100% implementation and hardware dependent . Triviality of the example also implies the triviality of the answer.

Comment: @PeterKrauss your question on math is same imprecise. What is the prefix? (4512)10 and (0045)10 do not have 45 as "prefix" as there is no `45` on the same significant digits. Prefix and postfix can be used when we talk about strings not numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would you like to optimize this any further ? What instructions do you want there to be in the final assembly ?

On the first page of [`xchg rax, rax`](https://github.com/AlexAltea/blog/blob/master/posts/2016-10-12-xchg-rax-rax-solutions.md) there is an example of several methods of assigning a zero value to a register. Some of which are longer or more efficient but they all do the same thing. Example:

`xor      eax,eax
lea      rbx,[0]
loop     $
mov      rdx,0
and      esi,0
sub      edi,edi
push     0
pop      rbp`

Comparison against a value is not such a rich world as assignment of a value. For comparison you basically have `test` or `cmp` or a check of the `ZF` flag.

I think that the most efficient way would be with a `test` instruction following a `sete` instruction to fetch the value of `ZF`, as can be seen in the link posted in tkausl's comment

Generally speaking, if you want your compiler to optimize you need to pass it the appropriate flag

See [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for GCC optimization

or [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1ack8f1.aspx) for MSVC optimization

Comment: See https://godbolt.org/z/MUtvYk  where we can to demonstrate that the optimization exist... Perhaps the main information to say "was optimized" is about `test` and `cmp` performance, as you highlighted... The compiler seems to adopt `test eax,eax`   as optimized version of  `cmp eax,0`... It is perhaps some marginally better performing instruction, so other question: there are a perfornace gain?

Comment: is3 compiles to
`48 83 ff 03       cmp rdi, 3
0f 94 c0           sete al`

while is_zero compiles to
`48 85 ff         test rdi, rdi
0f 94 c0        sete al`

which is one byte shorter. This would produce smaller binaries and *might* make them run faster, though this is not guaranteed.

From empirical test I made, their performance is almost identical and there is no rule which one will run faster, though is_zero on avg. runs for less time.

You should trust your compiler to generate good assembly instead of trying to find a way to force it to do as such.

Comment: Thanks for all @Mickey695. Seems that we can say that there are no "optimization method" (marginal  or no performance gain with `test`), we need only to take "minimal care" to avoid bad code production.  Here is the exact context of of the problem that generated the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2892097/70274

Comment: It's not even clear OP is using x86/64. And asking about such simple C code is completely irrelevant for the generated machine code. Optimisations should be left to the compiler in the first place. Until now, OP has not answered a lot of relevant questions, the one about **why** being the least.

Answer (score 0):

There is not too much to optimize in your code.

1. You can use the implementation defined pragmas or attributes to ensure that your  function will be inlined.
2. The return value should not be fixed length - just the processor native size integer value

for gcc

```
inline int __attribute__((always_inline)) is_zero(int64_t checkMe)
{   /* ensure that compiler will do some optimization */
   return checkMe == 0;
}
```

Why `int` instead of int64_t?

Lets consider the 8 bits microcontroller:

```
inline int __attribute__((always_inline)) is_zero(int64_t checkMe)
{   /* ensure that compiler will do some optimization */
   return checkMe == 0;
}

inline int64_t __attribute__((always_inline)) is_zero1(int64_t checkMe)
{   /* ensure that compiler will do some optimization */
   return checkMe == 0;
}

/* or even better */
inline uint8_t __attribute__((always_inline)) is_zero2(int64_t checkMe)
{   /* ensure that compiler will do some optimization */
   return checkMe == 0;
}
```

and the result:

```
is_zero:
        ldi r30,lo8(1)
        ldi r31,hi8(1)
        or r18,r19
        or r18,r20
        or r18,r21
        or r18,r22
        or r18,r23
        or r18,r24
        or r18,r25
        breq .L2
        ldi r30,lo8(0)
        ldi r31,hi8(0)
.L2:
        mov r24,r30
        mov r25,r31
        ret
is_zero1:
        ldi r30,lo8(1)
        or r18,r19
        or r18,r20
        or r18,r21
        or r18,r22
        or r18,r23
        or r18,r24
        or r18,r25
        breq .L4
        ldi r30,lo8(0)
.L4:
        mov r18,r30
        ldi r19,lo8(0)
        ldi r20,lo8(0)
        ldi r21,lo8(0)
        ldi r22,lo8(0)
        ldi r23,lo8(0)
        ldi r24,lo8(0)
        ldi r25,lo8(0)
        ret
is_zero2:
        ldi r30,lo8(1)
        or r18,r19
        or r18,r20
        or r18,r21
        or r18,r22
        or r18,r23
        or r18,r24
        or r18,r25
        breq .L6
        ldi r30,lo8(0)
.L6:
        mov r24,r30
        ret
```

Comment: Hi @P__J__  can you crate a new URL from  @tkausl's https://godbolt.org/z/Ys_RCz  and add there the a line with `int64_t is3(int64_t checkMe){return checkMe==3;}`  ?  Will be the core of the answer: the instruction `test    rdi, rdi`  **is faster** (? I suppose) tham  `cmp     rdi, 3`, so it is an automatic optimization. Them, your discussion about how to ensure it with pragmas, etc.

Comment: About my use of `int64_t` in the returning datatype, sorry (!), I edited the question. Yes, can be `int` or `_Bool`... no mater, it is only a "context illustration".

Comment: This is thevXY poroblem. The instructions used will depend on the optimisation options. The example is too trivial for any deeper considerations.